# Why override equals not work for adding same objects in Map?

Tags: java

If you look at this program , In Location class we override two methods (equals and hashcode) with respectively return false and 110. We are creating one instance of Location class and put in map two times. As we return false from equals method , why map overwrite last value with key ?

```
class Location {

        long latitude;
        long longitude;

        public Location(long latitude,int longitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 110;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Latitude := %d , Longitude :=%d ", latitude,longitude);
        }

    }

    Map<Location, String> locations = new HashMap<>();

    Location l1 = new Location(2,3); 
    locations.put(l1, "Mumbai");
    locations.put(l1,"Pune");       

    System.out.println(locations+ " with size of :"+locations.size());
```

Comment: why map overwrite last value with key ?  means??

Comment: My guess it that HashMap compares equality (`==`) as optimization before calling equals. Note that your equals method violates the contract of Object.equals, which requires reflexivity.

Comment: A quick glance at the [`HashMap` source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) (line 611 to start), will lead you to line 634 and `((k = p.key) == key` which is `true`.

Comment: `HashMap` relies on correct implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`. There are no guarantees of the behaviour otherwise.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Note that [you can do this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l634)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes . correct . it will check key with address OR equals with other key .

Comment: @AdityaPatel `true || false` is still true.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I thought internally it checks only equals method . not instance as well

Comment: It checks the instance equality first, and only if that differs does it test value equality.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes

Answer (score -1):

I looked in the `HashMap` implementation. Obviously Your `Location::equals` is never been called, because `==` is used to test the equality of the keys.
And the reason for this is – thanks to chrylis – You add the identical Location twice.
Change Your code:

```
Location l1 = new Location( 2, 3 );
locations.put( l1, "Mumbai" );

Location l2 = new Location( 2, 3 );
locations.put( l2, "Pune" );
```

Comment: Huh? The key type is `Location`, not `Integer`.

Comment: The key is _not_ the hash. The hash is used to group keys for efficiency.